# Automatic reloading of resources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, resources

Is there a way to automatically reload Spring resource file? 
I want to find out a simple way to change my configuration xml in runtime. Xml file is out of classpath folder.

Any ideas?

thx:)

Answer (score 4):

If you meant that you want to avoid redeploying your server to change your xml configuration, you can check JRebel http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the app contest you want to refresh, use ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh() or more specifically for the web environment , [AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.html) . You could look this up using the context:property-placeholder .

Answer (score 1):

Create your own extension to the ResourceBundle interface and use that to look up your strings instead of Spring. This way, you can control things like reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Spring provides [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) that can reload the properties file  through the [cacheSeconds](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setCacheSeconds%28int%29) setting.It support the properties files in the format of `*.properties` and the XML format used by  [Properties.loadFromXML()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29).

If your xml file is in other formats , you have to make your own resource loader by extending [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) , and implement your logic to parse the XML file  by overridding its [loadProperties(Resource resource, String filename)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#loadProperties%28org.springframework.core.io.Resource,%20java.lang.String%29) .