# Can a Spring Bean be re-assign a new value and how

Tags: spring, configuration

I have a Spring bean which gets new files from the file system when the file changes. Is it possible to assign the new file when the file contents change. What Spring class can I use to refresh the Spring beans value. Here is a simple configuraton, The file.xml allows new entries to be added to it. I then use a FileWatcher to be alerted of changes to the file. I want to attach the new file to the bean so that I can read those changes:

```
  <bean id="config" class="org.my.test.ResourceHandler">
    <property name="location" value="file:/path/to/file.xml"/>
  </bean>
```

When file.xml changes I detect the changes and want to refresh the ResourceHandler with the current contents. Is this possible with the Spring framework?

Comment: `config.refresh()`? What's the concrete problem?

Comment: look at the answer of Ken Chan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744003/automatic-reloading-of-resources-in-spring

Comment: I'll provide more detail.

Comment: Will calling refresh() pick up the new changes even without explicitly attaching the file?

Comment: What you've suggested requires loading the application context, but the context is loaded from a web configuration

Comment: Spring beans aren't immutable. Why not just make a setter and use `config.setLocation("someNewFile.xml")`? I will say, depending on the use case this can be dangerous though. If it's unique per user, consider using a scoped proxy bean.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the context of your problem, but I do believe you are taking the wrong approach. Beans generally are for inversion of control. To me it sounds that you need an implementation of the Observer Pattern. All classes that are interested on changes to your ResourceHandler should be observers of ResourceHandler.